# iPhone 4S capability to read android hidden files

Tags: iphone

I sent an email with hidden files from an android to my iPhone 4S. When I opened the mail attachment it's was several lines of boxes and com.apple.textencoding.   What are these files and how can I open them?

Comment: Please define "hidden files".